# Dump a database and scp it to a remote server with date hour suffix

Tags: tar, scp

I would like to dump a database and scp it to a remote server and suffix the file with date_hour.
Here is what I have done (of course it doesn't work) :

```
mysqldump -u root -p myDb > myDb.sql && \
  tar -cvzf myDb.tar.gz myDb.sql && \
  scp myDb.tar.gz root@x.x.x.x:myDb_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).tar.gz
```

What should be the right syntax?

Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get? The commands look Ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of typos, DNS, network, client/server file permissions and port issues (requiring a `-P` flag to scp) the only other thing that sticks out to me is that you haven't specified a path after the colon.

root@x.x.x.x:myDb_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).tar.gz

This means that the server gets to decide where that file is dumped.  If it's /tmp (which can be a security precaution) then it may not end up where you expect.

If you meant root's home folder, then you can either use

```
...x.x.x.x:/root/myDb_...
```

or you can use the shorthand for "user's home folder" the tilde (~)

```
...x.x.x.x:~/myDb_...
```

If that's not the solution, can you please update your question with the output of each command. :-)